# MVC-Project seems to be build partially - EditorTemplates breakpoints not hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll, build

I'm facing realy weired issue with my MVC5-project. When adding

```
@RenderBody()
@{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

to my `~/Views/Shared/Master.cshtml` an exception is thrown at runtime.
However, in my `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml` the same code will not be run.

It seems like, the `EditorTemplates`-folder (its content) is not beeing build as of breakpoints will also not be hit, saying

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

I've already deleted bin/obj folders, cleaned the ASP.NET Temp folder, cleaned and rebuilded my project, checked the project-settings, restarted local IIS...
Currently I'm running out of options. I even re-cloned my whole project to a new local folder. Still the same.

How can it happen that one breakpoint is hit, another one not? Even if they are in the same assembly?

**Edit #1**

The template is used with

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Start, "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_DateTimePicker.cshtml")
```

in another view. Breakpoints set there will be hit. Changes there also.

It renders at least some old version of my `_DateTimePicker.cshtml`, but never the current one. Where can I find the files locally which are used by `IIS`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was how I called the 'template'.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Start, "~/Views/Shared/_DateTimePicker.cshtml")
```

should be

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Start, "_DateTimePicker")
```

Not sure why the first version is not throwing an exception or gave me some hint.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because your application runs through that point on your Master.cshtml file. If you want the exception thrown or your break point hit on your DateTime.cshtml view, add it as a partial view on your Master.cshtml file.

```
Do this on your Master.cshtml:

@Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/DateTime")
```

Comment: I call the template with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Start, "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_DateTimePicker.cshtml")` in my `Setup.cshtml` view. Breakpoints in `Setup.cshtml` get hit, in `_DateTimePicker.cshtml` not.
But, at leas it renders something. Something old. Where can I find the deployed files locally?